# variable in a script is not seen inside the script (csh, tcsh)

Tags: bash, csh, tcsh

I wanted to set a variable indicating a directory and use it to access files in that directory.
So I wrote a simple script (note I didn't put #!/bin/csh in front)

file test :

```
set dir1=/tmp
ls -l $dir1
```

I did `chmod +x test` and ran `test` but it just shows my current directory like $dir1 is just null. I tried using {XX} to no avail.

And I want to do it without usig #!/usr/bin/env tcsh or #!/bin/csch or #!/bin/tcsh. Is it impossible? (I don't want to start a new shell but use the same aliases and other previous environment variables etc.)

What is wrong? I'm doing this in tcsh.

## ADD

I later found out

```
dir1=/tmp
ls $dir1
```

is the answer.

Comment: 'set' command in linux is not as in Windows!

Comment: The `ls` command is not built-in to your shell. The `dir` command is also not built in to your shell. If your question is about csh variable setting and expansion, then the changing `ls` to `dir` is not really part of the answer... Skipping the shebang does not avoid running a new shell. The way to execute commands inline in your shell in csh/tcsh is to use the `source` command.

Comment: Also, why is this question tagged **[tag:bash]**?

Comment: @ghoti what if I want to give it some arguments? (I want to use it with $1 $2.. ) using `source` I cannot give arguments, can I?

Comment: @ChanKim - if you want to give a script arguments, you are implying a new shell to run that script. It sounds like what you really want is an `alias` in tcsh (or a `function` in POSIX shell or bash).

Comment: @ghoti yes I need arguments, about 10 line procedures using environment variables I temporarily set in the shell which calls this script. I have several questions but will post it as a new question. (like how to check if a directory doesn't exist, without using shebang. I testsed but of course if [! -d dir1 ]) than.. endif doesn't work.

Comment: So... Usually, when I write stuff in csh, it's to prove wrong the people who tell me it can't be done. ("There. See? Yes, it's an ugly insecure hack .. but it *works* .. for now.") There have been multiple treatises detailing why you shouldn't program in csh/tcsh [(1)](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/), [(2)](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt), [(3)](http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/anti/csh/). Do consider redefining your requirements; you'll have less stress and find better help writing POSIX shell (or bash or zsh or pdksh or fish).

Comment: That said, if you build functionality you want in separate scripts that need to be run in-line, you can always define an `alias` for each one which will `source` the script in question. It will "behave" like POSIX functions, mostly.

Comment: @ghoti ok, that sounds like a good method. (alias + source). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the distinction between **shell variables**, which may be used interactively or within a script but are local to the script, versus **environment variables** which become part of the environment passed to programs which are called by the script.

In POSIX (or bash or related) shells, you can convert a shell variable to an environment variable using the `export` built-in command.

In csh/tcsh, the `set` command sets a shell variable, but the `setenv` command sets an environment variable. Once set, you can use an environment variable in your shell script the same way you would a shell variable, but that variable will be included in the environment of subshells or other programs that you run.

Note:

```
1% set foo=bar
2% echo $foo
bar
3% csh
1% echo $foo
foo: Undefined variable.
2%
```

vs

```
1% setenv foo bar
2% echo $foo
bar
3% csh
1% echo $foo
bar
2%
```

In the first example, the `set` command created a shell variable that was only visible within the context of the shell in which it was set.  In the second example, the `setenv` command created an *environment* variable that was passed to the subshell.

Note that setting a variable via either method *within the script* will not permit that variable to be passed back to the calling shell, as you would see using a POSIX shell function that uses curly braces.  For that sort of functionality in csh/tcsh, you'd probably have to rely on the `alias` command. For example, I use the following alias:

```
alias go 'cd `dirname \!:*`'
```

which lets me do this:

```
1% alias go 'cd `dirname \!:*`'
2% go /usr/local/etc/foo.rc
3% pwd
/usr/local/etc
4%
```

Look at the `History substitution` part of `man tcsh` to see how this work.

If you're trying to build a solution that depends on information being passed back to the parent shell, either use a different shell, or use backquote substitution with stdout on the commands you write, along with aliases.

Comment: This answer is more to the point so I'm choosing this one as the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: based on your comments, you need to run the script with the `source` command (see @ghoti's commnent).

Long answer: There are a number of different ways to run a shell script, with different implications for how it runs.

- The normal preferred way to run a script is to have the script start with a shebang (`#!`) line specifying the interpreter to use for it (/bin/sh, /bin/bash, etc), and then either place the script in a directory in your path and execute it by name, or specify the path to the script as your command (note that `./scriptname` is a special case of this, where the path is "right here").

  With this method, a subprocess running the specified interpreter is created and executes the script. Since the script executes in a subprocess, things like environment variables set in it do not affect the environment of the shell it was run from (i.e. setting `dir1=/tmp` only applies within the script, not after it's finished).
- You can also run a script by name or path if it doesn't have a shebang. This also creates a subprocess running some interpreter (which one is a bit of a crapshoot). There's no good reason to do this; use a shebang.
- You can run a script by explicitly invoking an interpreter, as in `sh /path/to/script`, `bash /path/to/script`, or `csh /path/to/script`. Note that if the script is in the current directory, a full path is not needed; its name is sufficient. This also runs the script in a subprocess, but uses the specified interpreter (ignoring the shebang line if there is one).

  This one sometimes causes trouble if you specify the wrong interpreter (e.g. using `sh` for a script that uses bash-only features) and should only be used if something prevents you from using the first option.
- Finally, you can run the script with the `source` command (e.g. `source /path/to/script` or `source scriptname` if it's in the current directory). Unlike the others, this does not create a subprocess; it tells the current shell to execute commands from the file. This means that that the script had better be written in the right syntax for your current shell; if you `source` a bash or sh script from csh or tcsh, it's not going to go well. It also means the shebang (if any) gets ignored.

  If you want environment variable definitions from the script to be available in the shell you ran the script from, this is the only way to do it. (Well, except in sh-like shells you can use the `.` command, 'cause that's a synonym for `source`.)

  Since any shebang line is ignored when the script is `source`d, you can include it or not. I tend to add a shebang to scripts that should be source`d, either giving the correct interpreter as a hint to users, or using a`#!/bin/echo`shebang to print a message if someone tries to run the script without`source`:

  ```
  #!/bin/echo source this script from csh: source
  ```

  ...which is kind of a hack, since `/bin/echo` isn't an interpreter; but it'll run the command `/bin/echo source this script from csh: source /path/to/script` which at least points the user in the right direction. Note that this doesn't protect against someone overriding the shebang with `sh`, `bash`, etc.

BTW, a couple of other notes on incompatible commands: as I said, `set` does completely different things in sh-like vs csh-like shells. In csh-like shells, you assign variables with `set var=value`, but in sh-like shells `set` sets the script's positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc), so `set var=value` sets `$1` to the string "var=value". Also, in your answer, you use the `dir` command -- that's not a unix command at all, it's a DOS command; this suggests you're running these scripts under Windows, in which case there's a whole other class of potential compatibility confusions lurking.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. One question, whaf if I run after `chmod +x test` and `test` which I did as I said in the question? I thought it doesn't generate a shell. Is it correct? (i'm in the middle of something but will test it). and I used `ls` not `dir`(my mistake, how incorrect am I ..I'll fix it.)

Comment: If you just use the script name (or path) to run it, it's creating a subprocess. Depending on whether the script has a shebang, you're getting either the first or second of the scenarios I described.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the shebang to your script to force tcsh to be used
otherwise the default shell will be used!!!
and your variable definition/assignation syntax may not work as expected!

Add the following first line to your script

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcsh
```

Comment: I want to do it without usig #!/usr/bin/env tcsh or #!/bin/csch or #!/bin/tcsh. Is it impossible? (I don't want to start a new shell but use the same aliases and other previous environment variables etc.)

Comment: @ChanKim When you run a script normally, it *always* runs in a new shell. If you have a shebang, that'll tell the OS which shell to use; without a shebang it'll be a bit unpredictable, but probably sh-like, not csh-like. This is important because sh-like shells have very different syntax from csh-like shells. In the case of your script, the problem is because `set` means completely different things in sh-like shells vs. csh-like shells. Basically, if you want to keep your sanity, use a proper shebang.

Comment: @GordonDavisson then, what if I want to use the variables I set in the shell, how should I start the script? If I use shebang, those environment I set will not be seen.

Comment: @ChanKim See my answer (and ghoti's comment).